# While using GoogleLogin there are no errors but when i click on sign in with google on my webpage a blank screen comes up why?

Tags: reactjs

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="432392491099-agrimk3fval54s93u7kp14mkqdk07dta.apps.googleusercontent.com">
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
        </React.StrictMode>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>,
);

import React from 'react';
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
export default function Login_Buttons (params) {

  const responseMessage = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  };
  const errorMessage = (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  };     
 
  return (

      <div className='m-4'>
          <div class="flex justify-center">
          <GoogleLogin onSuccess={responseMessage} onError={errorMessage} />
          </div>
          <br />
      </div>
  );
};
```

these are the two codes

[This is the popup when i click on sign in with google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHy7X.png)

i need it to show the login acc info which was coming fine when i used react-google-login but it was depreceated package so now i'm trying to use @react-auth/google